# insert a row every row that have value with the same value

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have this VBA function that already insert a blank row if the checked row have value.
Could someone help me fix my code? I want the inserted row have the extract the same value of the checked row. And all the next blank row would have this value too.

```
Sub InsertRowsAfter()
    Dim MyCell As Range
    For Each MyCell In Selection
        If MyCell.Value <> "" Then
            MyCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
        End If
    Next MyCell
End Sub
```

> From:  [image: From] _______ To:  [image: To]

Comment: Welcome to Super User,, your question is bit confusing, You have written Checked Row but the code shows is Selection !!. I'm unable to understand this,, **I want the inserted row have the extract the same value of the checked row. And all the next blank row would have this value too.** If next Rows are Blank then how it would have same value??

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. What I mean is “if a cell have value, insert a row, and fill all the next blank cell with the value of checked cell, do the same for the rest cell in the selected cell that have the value”. You may see my uploaded image to understand. Sorry for confusing.

Comment: sorry still not getting the issue,,, you are trying to insert row but not specified how many also insert value into blank cells ,, are they you are inserting or already there,,, and what is do the same for rest cells,, what are they blank or filled??

Answer (score 0):

Why insert a row if you already have blank rows?

Try the following:

```
Sub InsertRowsAfter()
    Dim MyCell As Range
    For Each MyCell In Selection
        If MyCell.Value = "" Then
            MyCell.Value = MyCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value
        End If
    Next MyCell
End Sub
```